# Twilio TaskRouter - how to include certain Unavailable workers to pick up tasks?

Tags: twilio

In our Twilio application we would like to use TaskRouter to distribute incoming calls. Suppose we would like to handle the following scenario:

All Workers login to front-end application and have their status set to Available. If there are any incoming calls, Workers receive them in the UI.

Some Workers have this custom attribute: `{"work_hours": [600, 1600], "phone_numbers": ["+1...", "+1..."]}`. If for some reason this Worker becomes Unavailable during their working hours set between `"work_hours"` attribute, we would still like to have incoming calls forwarded to their personal phones from `"phone_numbers"` attribute.

If the above fails, we would like to forward the incoming call to Voicemail.

Basically, my question is whether it is possible to include Unavailable workers to Workflows and Task Queues? The above scenario would most likely require 3 Task Queues: one for all Available Workers, one for Unavailable but with `"work_hours"` attributes where `taskrouter.currentTime` is between those hours and one for Voicemail.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Solutions Architect here!

I think that you may already found a solution for your problem, but in case someone else is having this problem, here's my solution:

The best way to do this is actually creating a new Activity on TaskRouter of type Unavailable with Work Hours that is is an available Activity. With that state created, you can set the worker availability to this state when they are on this use case, and with the Task Router Workflows, you can have specific queues for these agents and using the routing strategies, bring a task to this queue if necessary.

Regarding to call the agents on their personal phone numbers, you can create a conference between the original call and the agent's phone number and have them connected.

This is a bit tricky, but is completely possible.